# Physical Appearance of the Q

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-q

What do the Q look like?  Do the Q actually have any sort of physical form that humans can perceive, or are they incorporeal?

Answer (score 10):

**The Q are(most likely) beyond human perception**

In the Voyager episode "Death Wish" the crew is actually brought to the continuum.

The Continuum is manifested in this form so that it will "Fall within [human] comprehension."

There is a road that represents how the Q travel space and time, as well as various people and objects that the Q take turns 'being.'

That said, the Q tend to underestimate human abilities(even if they may fear our potential), so it's possible that the Q gave Voyagers crew a more-dumbed-down-than-necessary version of their reality. At the very least, the Q don't consider humanity capable of perceiving them.

Captain Picard is probably the human who came closest to perceiving what the Q are/what their reality is. In "All Good Things", he closes an anomaly that threatens the human race by co-coordinating three *Enterprise* crews across three moments in time, and even this seems to be barely scratching the surface of the level at which the Q exist.

The closest we see to a Q in its "natural" form may be when Q chases the Enterprise in the form of a sphere of energy in the pilot episode of TNG, *Encounter at Farpoint*(at about 11:40 in part 1). However, there's no real evidence that this sphere isn't just another form Q is slipping into for his own amusement.

Answer (score -5):

I believe this is an image of the Q in their 'natural' form.
It came from the episode "Hide and Q".
[image]

Comment: While it'd be nice if you explained *why* you believe this, it is incorrect. If you watch the first scene after the opening credits, you get the following dialog. Picard: "You're no Starfleet admiral, Q." Q: "Neither am I an Aldebaran serpent, Captain, but you accepted me as such." You can read about [Aldebaran serpents on Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Aldebaran_serpent).